# How do I sort a 2d array based on the values of another array?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

So i have to read some lines of text off a text file

> S5555;100 70 70 100
>   S3333;50 50 50 50
>   S2222;20 50 40 70
>   S1111;90 80 90 85
>   S4444;70 80 90 50

I'm supposed to turn the texts into 2 arrays. One array stores the ID of a student and the other array stores the marks of the students (2d array).

Now I am required to sort the student ID in alphabetical order. How do i sort the 2d array based on how i sort the 1d array?

Comment: Anything you tried so far?

Comment: Just realized I'm dumb. I could have turn the text into an array and then sort it first...

Comment: Do not separate data that belongs together into different arrays. Create objects for course (name of course, mark) and student (id, list of courses). Use a generic list for the students instead of a fixed sized array. Read Jon Skeets blog about the [Anti-Pattern: Parallel Collections](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/)

Answer (score 0):

*Full disclosure:* I'm a C programmer, not a C# programmer, so this may not be the standard C# approach.  Regardless, it will work, it is readable, and it makes sense.  This is the sort of thing I would do in c++ or java, so I bet it carries over to c#.

I'm going to take a page from my old-school C background and say that I think the concept of a [struct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29) may be helpful here.

If you are programming c#, you probably know what a class is, right?  A struct is just a class that has all of its internal variables public.  If I had to read a list of employees with id#'s and salaries from a file and then sort them by id number, I would have a struct like this:

```
public struct employee
{
    int idnum;
    int yearly_salary;
    String name;
}
```

each time I declare a new employee variable, it comes with 3 "fields" (`idnum`, `yearly_salary`, `name`).  Look at this example.  It creates 2 new employee strucs named emp1 and emp2.

```
employee emp1;
emp1.name = "Lisa Goodwin";
emp1.yearly_salary = 129200;
emp1.idnum = 3911;

employee emp2;
emp2.name = "Sevn Rushbjorn";
emp2.yearly_salary = 39800;
emp2.idnum = 8721;
```

If we wanted to print the salary of the employee with the lowest id#, we could do the following:

```
if(emp1.idnum < emp2.idnum)
{
    Console.WriteLine("salary = ${0}\n", emp1.yearly_salary);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("salary = ${0}\n", emp2.yearly_salary);
}
```

Most importantly of all, when you swap 2 employees in an array, of course, all of their corresponding values get swapped.

```
employee emps[4];
//...... initialize vars from file or whatever...

swap<employee>(emps[3], emps[2]);
```

Using these concepts, you can compare id#'s in your sort method, (which I assume you are writing yourself because this sounds like homework), and use c#'s standard swap function to swap the 2 employees (or, in your case, students).

Simply adapt my "employee" example to students, and this should work fine.